# Help needed in this question. I have tried by equating the potential difference across each network. But, the answer I am getting is too complex

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac

enter image description here

[image: This is the whole picture of the circuit. This has been in my mind for many days. I just can't leave it. I think, every term is quite straight-forward]

[image: I am sorry for my bad handwriting. But, I can't spot any kinda mistake in here. The final expression is just not correct. It is not matching the general form the question has given at last. Please help]

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a schematic editor available to you (if you are running on a desktop PC, anyway.) You should grow into using it, as I must now do:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJ4guN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that since \$V_{_\text{O}}\$ is referenced to my given ground, I don't need to specify two nodes or two terminals for it. The reference is assumed, now. Similarly, the schematic is a little bit simplified.

The KCL is just (out-flowing currents in green, in-flowing currents in red, above):

$$\overbrace{\frac{V_{_\text{O}}}{Z_{_\text{L}}}+\frac{V_{_\text{O}}}{R_2}+\frac{V_{_\text{O}}}{R_1+Z_{_\text{C}}}}^{\text{out-flowing}}=\overbrace{\frac{V}{Z_{_\text{L}}}}^{\text{in-flowing}}$$

Which solves out as:

$$\frac{V_{_\text{O}}}{V}=\frac{R_2\left(R_1\,C\,s + 1\right)}{\left(R_1+R_2\right)L\,C\,s^2 + \left(R_1\,R_2\,C + L\right)s + R_2}$$

If you replace \$s=j\,\omega\$ (assuming \$\sigma=0\$) then you should easily reach the solution expression provided to you.

Note: Get and use [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html). It's free to use and very nice. Here's how I approached the problem:

```
var('r1 r2 vx vs c l s')
zc = 1/s/c
zl = s*l
simplify( solve( Eq( vx/zl + vx/r2 + vx/(r1+zc), vs/zl), vx )[0] / vs )

r2*(c*r1*s + 1)/(c*l*r1*s**2 + c*l*r2*s**2 + c*r1*r2*s + l*s + r2)
```

That's all there is to it. Simple. No mistakes. (Computers are really good at keeping track of things without making human mistakes.)

Comment: Maybe not schematic edittor but something like python, mathematica, mapple to help them with math

Comment: @anhnha Yes. It is so much easier that way. Fewer mistakes. But you have to know what how to do it by hand, as well, before going on to using something like sympy. I'll add a sympy script for the OP, though. Probably a good idea.

Comment: Your answer was the perfect thing I needed. Thanks for that. But, if possible can you point out where exactly I have gone wrong with my approach?

Comment: @RayonCherry I'd rather not struggle to read and decode your writing. It would occupy time I can ill afford to spend. It should be possible for you to compare what I wrote against your own writing. I used very easy to read computer generated equation forms. If you pinpoint something specific, I could take a look at that. But your writing is difficult for me. Easier for you to check, than for me, by quite a long ways I think.

Comment: @RayonCherry Given that solution you should be able to identify at which step you messed up. Expecting others not only to provide a solution but to then back-track and identify your errors is too much. The finding your point of error is the best part of the learning experience left to you since you now have the solution.